# Login with active directory

Tags: sql, sql-server, authentication, active-directory

I installed SQL Server 2019 and add active directory user with sysadmin permission for login, and I can login when execute SSMS with run as different user, but when I want to connect with active directory - password option it failed. Error message:

> "A connection was successfully established with the server, but then an error occurred during the login process. (provider: SSL Provider, error: 0 - The target principal name is incorrect.) (.Net SqlClient Data Provider)"

When check trust server certificate error message:

> Login failed for user ''. (.Net SqlClient Data Provider)

Error in errorlog (use ssms on sql server):

> 2020-07-22 13:11:13.730   Logon   Error: 18456, Severity: 14, State: 58.

> 2020-07-22 13:11:13.730   Logon   Login failed for user ''. Reason: An attempt to login using SQL authentication failed. Server is configured for Integrated authentication only. [CLIENT: ]

Error in errorlog (use sql client on my pc):

> 2020-07-22 13:11:39.960   Logon   Error: 18456, Severity: 14, State: 6.

> 2020-07-22 13:11:39.960   Logon   Login failed for user 'canymescom\USR-PortalFarm'. Reason: Attempting to use an NT account name with SQL Server Authentication. [CLIENT: 172.20.10.220]

Result of setspn -x:

```
Checking domain DC=example,DC=com
Processing entry 0
found 0 group of duplicate SPNs.
```

Comment: Have you looked at the error log? `exec sp_ReadErrorLog`

Comment: Yes, I checked SQL Server and Windows Authentication mode but when I tried from ssms `2020-07-22 12:12:20.900 Logon Error: 18456, Severity: 14, State: 58.
2020-07-22 12:12:20.900 Logon Login failed for user ''. Reason: An attempt to login using SQL authentication failed. Server is configured for Integrated authentication only. [CLIENT: <local machine>]  `

Comment: You are not passing in a domain account to connect to the server. Probably your connectionstring is wrong or you are launching the application with an account that is not recognized by the domain controller.

Comment: Did you previously have the SQL service running under the Local System account and then was changed to run under a domain account?

Comment: No, the server was connected to the domain when I installed it and I added both users(sa and my domain user) at the same time

Comment: Run this command, and report the output of any duplicates found as an edit to your question:   *setspn -x*